External table 'dbo.alltype' is not accessible because location does not exist or it is used by another process.DB-Lib error
I am trying to access data from Azure Synapse,getting the below error
""External table 'dbo.alltype' is not accessible because location does not exist or it is used by another process.DB-Lib error".
My part is retrieving data so I am not worrying about how the table has been created and with what parameters.
Below is the code
def read_query_data(self, query, db=""):
        result = {"STATUS": "FAIL", "MESSAGE": "Error in {} read_query_data".format(self.ds_type),
                  "DATA": pd.DataFrame()}
        try:
            df = pd.read_sql(query, self.connection)
            df.columns = [col.upper() for col in df.columns]
            result["DATA"] = df.fillna("")
            result["STATUS"] = "SUCCESS"
            result["MESSAGE"] = ""
        except Exception as e:
            result["MESSAGE"] += "\nError(s): {}".format(str(e.args))
            log.error(result["MESSAGE"])
            traceback.print_exc()
        return result

where query is SELECT * FROM dbo.alltype

Could you please provide where the external table is created serverless sql pool or dedicated sql pool?

I have been trying to access both dedicated as well as created one,will there be a difference?

The external table 'dbo.alltype' is not accessible because the location does not exist or it is being used by another process.
The user to whom you are trying to connect to the SQL database does not have access to read data from the external table location attached to the External table. This may be the reason for receiving the error while reading the table. If the table is from the serverless SQL pool/dedicated SQL pool and the external location is blob storage or ADLS attached to Synapse, you can use Active Directory MFA authentication. You can use the code below:
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}', host='<hostName>', database='<databaseName>',
                      user='<ADUserName>', Authentication='ActiveDirectoryInteractive')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM <tableName>")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)


The data table will be read successfully as shown below:


Hey,for this code to be working I have to download sql driver in my laptop,instead is there any sdk which I can download using PIP,which helps in resolving issue faster

If you don't want to install driver the use jdbc driver.
